# IPMI and Recursive AD group permissions

Tags: active-directory, ipmi, supermicro

It seems that SuperMicro's IPMI service does not allow for Active Directory permissions to be recursive, that is, a user in a group, with that group in a group that has admin permissions.

Is there a workaround for this, or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that It's just a certain firmware or something that doesn't let recursion happen. With a previous version of ipmi it works fine.

I'll update this with future findings